# Setting a linear-gradient on the table that will change color on the dark scheme of outlook

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am trying to set a solid color background that will cover the first cell and some part of the second.

Unfortunately, after testing it on dark scheme of outlook email client, it was not able to darken the background color (as it would do with background-color) and text is no longer visible.

I guess outlook skips the background-image formatting, but I would not be able to achieve the same result only with background-color.

Question: is there a workaround to have the same effect that also works on dark scheme??

```html
<table role="presentation" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border: 0; border-spacing: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="padding:0; background-image:linear-gradient(#D7DDDA 0%, #D7DDDA 100%); background-size: 100% 70%; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 442.5px;" width="auto">
      <table role="presentation">

        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0;" align="center">
            <p width="639.4666666666667" style="padding: 26.6pt 0 0 0; width: 479.6pt; font-family: 'FiraGo Light', Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-style: normal; font-size: 16pt; line-height: 24pt; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; color: #3a3735;">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td style="padding: 0;" align="center">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Rooms Hotel Kokhta Camping" width="639.4666666666667" style="height: auto; padding: 23.4pt 0 0 0; margin: 0; display: block;">
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The background-image:linear-gradient... is actually a dark mode hack, identified recently, to force email clients to stop changing originally dark backgrounds. Fairly certain this was specifically for Gmail though, but I'm guessing this has broader reach. What Outlook client specifically are you trying to find support for? There are so many!!!

Comment: I am testing on the latest outlook from app store on mac. This hack would be wonderful only if we could override the dark mode effect on the text color. Would be cool to hear some more thoughts about that too! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to target Outlook for Mac with this:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .go-red { color:#FF0000!important; }
}
```

Just add the go-red class to your p tag. I tested this in OL Office 365 Dark (macOS) via Litmus